# Sitecore Standard Values Presentation Details

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have a general print layout that I want to apply to a lot of different types of content.
These types of content all inherit from the same base template so I figured I would attache this layout to the base's standard value's presentation details.
I applied this layout to the print device but it seems like this is being overriden by the standard values of the more specific templates.

I want to know if there's a way to defer standard value's presentation details at the device level.
In my case I mean that I want to know if there's a way to have all the content types I want to point to the print device of the base template but point to their standard value's presentation details for the other devices.

I thought just leaving the more specific templates' print devices blank would accomplish that but it seems like that is not the case.
If that is then I'm guessing the standard values were overridden before and I will need to reset them.
If that is the case then I would like to know if there is a way to reset presentation details at the device level (I haven't seen a way to do this).

I am using Sitecore 6.6 rev 140410

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is very similar to the one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25880950/1506793), though that question does not mention Standard Values, explicitely. My answer is the same, so I will repeat it here:

To answer your question, directly, there is no way to apply an update of the presentation details of a template to templates that inherit from it that have had their presentation details changed without losing the changes.

The solution described in the blog post you linked to is the best solution for updating inherited presentation details in this manner. IMHO, I believe that this functionality should have been built into Sitecore long ago as a separate button on the ribbon, and you may choose to add one if you are so inclined. If you do not have the time to do so however, creating an admin page that you later delete from the site after using is a perfectly viable solution as well.

**Clarification and Elaboration**

I should clarify that, unfortunately, the "inherit if unchanged" logic for presentation details is not device specific, but rather applies to the presentation details as a whole. If you are willing to do so (which I am sure that you are not), you can reset all of the templates presentation details, which will remove any changes that you have made while adding details from the inherited templates.